Factorisation of continuous maps II
I was studying general topology when a question came to my mind.
Following the same spirit of this previous question (in fact, only reversing arrows), I'd like to know about the following problem: given two continuous maps f and g having the same codomain (not only as set, but as topological space) with f injective, under which conditions there exists a continuous map h such that  = f ∘ h?
It is known that for a map h to exists set-theoretically it is necessary and sufficient that the image of g is a subset of the image of f. This assumed, there may be multiple maps h, whereas the injectivity of f is sufficient for h to be unique. My question is basically when this h is continuous.

In the $f$ injective case - with $\mathrm{Im}(g)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(f)$ -  the set-theoretically unique map $h$ is continuous (in general!) if and only if $f$ is a subspace inclusion. Recall subobjects in the category of spaces are not subspaces!
Let's see this in detail. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous injection. With no loss of generality, view $X$ as a genuine subset of $Y$. My claim is that what you want holds iff. $X$, as a space, has the subspace topology coming from $Y$. If this is true, then the result is quite well-known (corestriction of maps): if $g:Z\to Y$ is continuous and $g(Z)\subseteq X$, $g$ factors through $X\subset Y$. For $U\subseteq X$ is open iff. $U=X\cap V$, $V\subseteq Y$ some open set, and $\tilde{g}^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(X\cap V)=g^{-1}(V)$ is open in $Z$ in this case, $\tilde{g}$ the corestriction of $g$, $Z\to X$, so $\tilde{g}$ is continuous.
Now suppose that $h$ is always continuous when it exists. Consider the space $X'$ whose set is $X$ and whose topology is the subspace topology coming from $Y$. $g:X'\hookrightarrow Y$ of course has $\mathrm{Im}(g)=\mathrm{Im}(f)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(f)$, so by assumption $h:X'\to X$ is continuous. But, pointwise, $h$ is just the identity map. Then continuity means to say that every open subset of $X$ is open in $X'$. However, every open subset of $X'$ is open in $X$ too simply by the supposed continuity of $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$. So $X'=X$ as spaces i.e. $f$ really is a subspace inclusion (without more context, if $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ we could only have said that the topology on $X$ refines the subspace topology).
